# How to fix CORS error in PHP? (CORS did not succeed)

Tags: php

So I'm trying to make an endpoint to access my database with and it works just fine in postman, but when calling the `GET` request on my website i get a CORS error:

> Query for foreign site blocked: The same origin policy does not allow remote resource reading http://IPGOESHERE/cordova/endpoint/log.php?id=-1. (Cause: The CORS query failed).)

I've tried googling but was unable to find anything useful.

My server-sided code is in 2 files which i have included below:

models/Log.php:

```
class Log {

  // database connection and table name
  private $conn;
  private $table_name = "logging";

  // object properties
  public $ID;
  public $UserID;
  public $Handling;
  public $Date;

  // constructor with $db as database connection
  public function __construct($db) {
      $this->conn = $db;
  }

  // read products
  function read($id) 
  {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name;

        if ($id != '-1') {
            // select query
            $query .= " WHERE logging.ID = ".$id;
        }
        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

log.php

```
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// database connection will be here
include_once '../database.inc';
include_once '../models/Log.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
  $id = $_GET['id'];

  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->getConnection();

  $Log = new Log($db);
  // query products
  $stmt = $Log->read($id);
  $num = $stmt->rowCount();

  // check if more than 0 record found
  if ($num > 0) {
      $products_arr = array();
      $products_arr["records"] = array();

      while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          extract($row);

          $product_item = array(
              "ID" => $ID,
              "UserID" => $UserID,
              "Handling" => $Handling,
              "Date" => $Date,
          );

          array_push($products_arr["records"], $product_item);
      }

      // set response code - 200 OK
      http_response_code(200);

      // show products data in json format
      echo json_encode($products_arr);
  } else {
      // set response code - 404 Not found
      http_response_code(404);

      // tell the user no products found
      echo json_encode(
          array("message" => "No log found")
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: "a CORS error"  — Don't be vague. Tell us what the error message says!

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, the error was in my local language, here is a translated version:
Query for foreign site blocked: The same origin policy does not allow remote resource reading http://IPGOESHERE/cordova/endpoint/log.php?id=-1. (Cause: The CORS query failed).

Comment: You should precise how you try to access your endpoint, the keyword `cordova` suggests that you use a cordova app? If so, did you whitelist your endpoint url in the cordova config file?

Comment: The website uses Cordova, but the server is just plain PHP.
But i access my endpoint like this (on the webiste): `app.request.getJSON('${app.data['serverip']}/endpoint/log.php?id=-1', (response) => {}`

Comment: Execute this endpoint and validate Access Control headers are present, eg: `curl -I http://yourhost.com/endpoint/log.php?id=-1`

Comment: Do you also have this url whitelisted in your cordova config.xml?

Comment: Just tried the curl command and it seems all headers are being sent with, here is what it outputted:
`Headers: {[Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *], [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, true], [Access-Control-Max-Age, 1000], [Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding]...}`
And @Kaddath i got another endpoint which works fine without being added to any Cordova config file, since the endpoint it self is plain PHP.

Comment: maybe we are missing what is exactly different between the working endpoint and this one. Do you use `getJSON` too for the working one? (is it jQuery's getJSON?). Also, do you have a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` in your cordova index.html?

Comment: It's jQuery's getJSON, and yes i use it for both, and i don't even have the cordova.js imported right now and the problem is still there and still only for this endpoint.

Comment: The question about the meta tag is still valid though, because it's not cordova-dependant

Comment: I don't believe it's causing this, because the other endpoint works? But here is the security-policy from my header (index)
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">`

Comment: you can still try to add `; connect-src 'self' http://IPGOESHERE/*;` (first `;` is to end the `default-src` declaration), it actually should be there anyway. Are the 2 endpoints on the same IP?

Comment: Yes we actually have multiple endpoints on the same IP as the one having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was due to php not allowing me to use the class name "Log" renamed everything called log & it now works flawlessly.